# explorer.exe keeps restarting due to faulty shell extension, how to remove it?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I installed a shell extension that keeps crashing, thus making explorer.exe crashing.

As a result, I can't open anything, even a command prompt.

How to remove the faulty shell extension?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press CTRL-ALT-DELETE
2. Choose `Log out`
3. Click on `Restart` while pressing SHIFT
4. Enter your password
5. Click `Troubleshoot`
6. Click `Advanced options`
7. Click `Startup Settings`
8. Click `Restart`
9. Press `F6` for "Enable safe mode with command prompt"
10. You now have an administrator command prompt, so remove the shell extension with something like `regsvr32 /u "C:\path\to\TheShellExtension.dll"`